# Why are errors sometimes larger when using spo.curve_fit with absolute_sigma = False?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

spo.curve_fit takes the parameter absolute_sigma.

From the documentation:

> If False, sigma denotes relative weights of the data points. The returned covariance matrix pcov is based on estimated errors in the data, and is not affected by the overall magnitude of the values in sigma. Only the relative magnitudes of the sigma values matter.
>
> If True, sigma describes one standard deviation errors of the input data points. The estimated covariance in pcov is based on these values.

Why is the estimated error sometimes bigger when this parameter is False than when it's True?

Comment: Why do expect the estimated error never to be larger when absolute_sigma=False?

Comment: @xnx I don't really understand what's being computed when we don't give it absolute errors tbh. I suppose what I'm thinking in my head is that if we don't give an absolute error then we just have error from the fitting, whereas if we do give it an absolute error we have error from the fitting but also from the values themselves. As we have two sources of error, I would expect the latter to be bigger.

Comment: @DanielMarx This is not what it's doing. The source code is here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L454